# PseudoTerminal - Not read from stdin

Tags: c++, pty

I am creating a class where I can create multiple threads that are pseudo terminals, in order to talk to each one of them I have to create multiple files / Fifos to talk to each pseudo terminal slave, because taslking to the stdin makes any created pseudoterminal listen, the problem is that when using a fifo for input it does not work.

Here is the code

```
void * Terminal::tTerminal(void * pvParameters)
{
    Terminal (*self) = reinterpret_cast<Terminal*>(pvParameters);
    fd_set inFds;
    //dup2(self->in, STDIN_FILENO);
    for (;;)
    {
        FD_ZERO(&inFds);
        FD_SET(self->in, &inFds);
        FD_SET(self->masterFd, &inFds);
        if (select(self->masterFd + 1, &inFds, &inFds, NULL, NULL) == -1)
        {
            printf("select");
        }


        if (FD_ISSET(self->in, &inFds))
        {
            self->numRead = read(self->in, self->buf, BUF_SIZE);
            if (self->numRead <= 0)
                exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

            if (write(self->masterFd, self->buf, self->numRead) != self->numRead)
                printf("partial/failed write (masterFd)");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("partial/failed write (masterFd)");
            fflush(stdout);
        }

        if (FD_ISSET(self->masterFd, &inFds))
        {
            self->numRead = read(self->masterFd, self->buf, BUF_SIZE);
            if (self->numRead <= 0)
                exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

            if (write(self->out, self->buf, self->numRead) != self->numRead)
                printf("partial/failed write (STDOUT_FILENO)");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("partial/failed write (STDOUT_FILENO)");
            fflush(stdout);
        }
}
```

For further notices the Fifos are created correctly, the file descriptors are not 0, the master and slave are running, the only problem is in:

```
FD_ISSET(self->in, &inFds)
```

Which means it is not set,

Thanks

Comment: Can `self->in` perhaps be larger than `self->masterFd`?

Comment: How can I chech that? or are you talking about their int values?

Comment: @G.Sliepen if you are talking about their int values masterfd is 3 and self->in is 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make sure the first argument to `select()` is the *highest* of all possible filedescriptors plus one, so:

```
select(std::max(self->masterFd, self->in) + 1, &inFds, &inFds, NULL, NULL)
```

Comment: Thank you that was the problem, can you explain why it needs to be the greater? Many thanks ;)

Comment: Because the first parameter tells `select()` up to which filedescriptor it should check for. From the manpage: "nfds is the highest-numbered file descriptor in any of the three sets, plus 1."

Comment: Amazing, I was reading a book but it didn't said nothing about that ;) Again, thanks

Comment: Bad book :) But what made you fill in `self->masterFd + 1` in the first place?

Comment: It was Linux Programming Interfaces, theoretically was one of the best, maybe I misread that part. 

It did nothing, it simply gave errors in the ISSET call, so when I wrote to self->in it didn't send it to self->masterFd

Comment: You could try suggesting to the author of that book that it should mention exactly what the first argument is for. Maybe it will be fixed in the next edition then :)